# initialize a TextField from a variable in a controller and using Fxml

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, model-view-controller, fxml

I use Javfx and Fxml file to do an application.
I would like initialize Textfield with variable data in controller but i have an error :

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Romain/Desktop/DroneKit/out/production/DroneKit/sample/sample.fxml:132

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.awt.TextField field sample.Controller.Vitesse to javafx.scene.control.TextField
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

for have that error i used 3 files :

my main file :

```
package sample;



import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    private  Stage m_primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        m_primaryStage=primaryStage;
        m_primaryStage.setTitle("Drone Plane");
        m_primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        m_primaryStage.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

my controller :

```
package sample;


import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable, MapComponentInitializedListener  {
    private int VitesseRef;
    private double HauteurRef;

    @FXML
    private TextField Vitesse;


    @FXML
    private TextField Hauteur;


 {...}  


    public Controller(){
        Point = new ArrayList<Cordonnée>();
        try {
            python = new DroneJava();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        VitesseRef=3;
        HauteurRef=2.5;
        Vitesse = new TextField();
        Hauteur = new TextField();
        Vitesse.setText(String.valueOf(VitesseRef));
        Hauteur.setText(String.valueOf(HauteurRef));
    }
```

and my Fxml file :

```
 {...}    
    <GridPane prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="15.0">
                                                             <columnConstraints>
                                                                 <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="295.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="68.0" />
                                                                 <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="532.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="532.0" />
                                                             </columnConstraints>
                                                             <rowConstraints>
                                                                 <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                                 <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                                             </rowConstraints>
                                                             <children>
                                                                 <Label text="Vitesse :" />
                                                                 <Label text="Hauteur :" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                                 <TextField fx:id="Vitesse" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                                                                 <TextField fx:id="Hauteur" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                                                             </children>
                                                         </GridPane>
 {...}
```

If i don't initialize the two Textfield in my custructor of my controller;
The excution return an NullPointer Exception on the Vitesse.setText.. 
So someone know how initialize an Textfield with an variable ?

Comment: Have you tried initializing your FXML components inside an `initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)` method, implementing `initializable`?

Comment: In your `StackTrace` it clearly hints at you using `AWT` imports instead of `JavaFX` imports. `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.awt.TextField field sample.Controller.Vitesse to javafx.scene.control.TextField`. I am guessing `import java.awt.*;` is your problem.

Comment: ok thx .. i don't see i don't use the good library ;)